# Signalr/hubs js high response time

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

When i check network activity of my site in chrome developer tools i found that singalr/hubs script it taking long time to response. i have attached screenshot. is it normal or something wrong with implementation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very normal for Server Sent Events. Client opens one connection on server and they use this connection for communucation.

[image]

Check this [article](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e11374) for detail.