# Watching SignalR request and response in browser

Tags: browser, request, signalr, signalr.client

I am using SignalR for inform users in realtime.But there is problem.I want to find why there is problem.But in browser when i clik f12 and chose network tab there is no request and response altough SignalR works well
here is my chrome console.When jquery I see request but for signalR there is no reuest or response.And also in network tab there is no WS(web socket)..

[image: Here is my chrome console]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signalr/hubs js high response time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872509/signalr-hubs-js-high-response-time)

Comment: Sentences may different but actually you are asking same thing you can check my answer this is normal for server sent events.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel my problem is different.There is no WS(web socket) in network tab in my browser

Comment: Because this is server sent events, you will not see ws.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel how can I see Signalr request and response?

Comment: On server sent events there will be one connection your client subscribe itself to server so they use this connection to communicate. If you want to see more detail you can use. You can enable [tracing](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#javascript)

Answer (score 2):

When you click `F12` on Browser,There is one functionality like `WS(Web Socket)` in `Network` tab.From that you can check the details of `SignalR`

Please see below image

[image]

Comment: I edited question.And I add my screen.There is no WS(Web Socket) in my network tab